# How to set BottomNavigationView inside Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-jetpack, android-navigation-graph

I have one activity and few fragments. I set up my activity with `NavController` and navigation graph like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_activity_main) as NavHostFragment
    navController = navHostFragment.findNavController()

}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```

In this navigation graph I take care of splash screen, login, register fragment and going to main fragment which has a `BottomNavigationView` with two sub fragments.

I made a menu for bottomNavView fragments and made a graph for them, menu id's match with bottom nav graph id's.

My layout looks like this:

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_main"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_Navigation_view"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/bottom_view_nav_graph" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_Navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In main fragment I am trying to set up bottom nav view with navigation graph like this:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val appCompat = requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity

    val navHostFragment = appCompat.supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_main) as NavHostFragment
    val navController = navHostFragment.findNavController()

    binding.bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)

}
```

However I keep getting this exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ak.chatter, PID: 1937
java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
    at com.ak.chatter.ui.main.MainFragment.onViewCreated(MainFragment.kt:34)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:332)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:900)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8347)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
```

Comment: the shared layout is for the activity right?

Comment: No, shared layout is main fragment layout

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type 
androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
```

You try to cast a null to a non-null.

The `null` is got from `appCompat.supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_main)` statement.

Because the `supportFragmentManager` is used as the fragment manager of fragments that are **hosted by a fragment**. Although the `supportFragmentManager` should manage fragments that are **hosted by an activity**.

Whereas the `childFragmentManager` should be used instead to manage fragments that are hosted by another fragment.

So, to solve this replace `supportFragmentManager` with `childFragmentManager` in the main fragment class:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val appCompat = requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity

    val navHostFragment = appCompat.childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_main) as NavHostFragment
    val navController = navHostFragment.findNavController()

    binding.bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)

}
```

Comment: for me the childFragmentManager is get from the fragment, not from appCompat